# Html.LabelFor Specified Text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Anyone got any idea on how to specify text when using `Html.LabelFor(c=>c.MyField)`.  It's just `MyField` might not be an appropriate name to display on screen, you may want "The Super Fantastic Field" instead, but there doesn't appear to be any overloads.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You use [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx):

```
[Display(Name = "My Field")]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Setting the [`ResourceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.resourcetype.aspx) property on your attribute will allow you to use a resource file.

(Prior to .NET 4 use [`System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) with the caveat that the display name must be a compile-time constant.)

Comment: You're the winner.  You've got to have `using System.ComponentModel;` though.

Comment: I have my code generator spit these out automatically, inserting spaces between Pascal-cased words.  Works like a charm!

Comment: Although this solution looks quite nice, I get `Error 381 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`. So this solution seems to be bad for l18n.

Comment: @moose I've updated the answer to reflect the new-in-.NET-4 [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) which allows the use of a resource file.

If you're not yet on 4/4.5, the old [`System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) can be extended like so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432520/33533

Comment: @CodeBlend I was using T4 to generate the model classes with appropriate attributes.  I had a method that split the string on capital letters and then joined again with a space.  (It's been 3 years, so don't have the code in front of me at the moment...)

Comment: I have several issues with this. I think this is a good solution, however, check this page for another approach. https://sheldons.me/2014/10/06/mvc-5-placeholders-prompts-and-watermarks/

Answer (score 56):

Easy solution just add the following in the view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(c=>c.MyField, "My Field")
```

Answer (score 26):

There is a new overload in MVC 3 so you should be able to specifiy custom test for the labelfor helper.

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdCode, "Friendly Name")

Answer (score 3):

I haven't downloaded v2 yet, so I can't test, but I believe it works like DynamicData, in which case you'd do something like this on your model:

```
[Display(Name = "The Super Fantastic Field")]
public string MyField {get;set;}
```

Comment: Display isn't available, and intellisense can't find it in any libs either.

Comment: Add a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll and add using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

Comment: Rather, add reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from the GAC (ie in the .NET tab of add references)

Comment: I use DataAnnotations already, so the reference isn't the problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry - that's apparently Silverlight3/.NET 4.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28VS.100%29.aspx   I think DisplayName is going to do what you want, as itsmecurtis suggests.  Here's more on that: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/08/19/DisplayNameAttributeInMVC.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways 
1"direct annotations" 
2"Annotatinos with a resource" 
Direct annotations

```
[Display(Name = "My Field")]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Annotatinos with a resource

```
[Display(Name = "My_Field",ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
public string MyField { get; set; }
```

Second way will require to add a value in resource file probably named as  **Resource.resx**.
Use which suits your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked out CP1 yet but I read over Scott's release of it and I seem to recall that the code was generated by T4. I suppose you could always mod that, but I would suspect that they will provide overloads in CP2.

Edit: The source is always available and thus you could just mod the method, change the T4 generator, and you'll be good to go. Also put in a ticket or request (somehow) for that mod so it gets worked into the next version.

Comment: Shame, I'm doing a work preview but it's not really viable as our field names are quite spurious compared to their description counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 overloads. Several offer second parameter of "string labelText", which you would set to "The Super Fantastic Field".