# How to use and/or localize DisplayAttribute with ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DisplayName attribute from Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources)

I am trying to figure out how to get the DisplayAttribute in my MVC 2 ViewModel to work with the Html.LabelFor() helper.

Neither

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Localization.Labels))]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

nor

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Display(Name = "test")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

seem to work. Localizing the Required Attribute works as expected:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Test", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization.Labels))]
```

I am using VS2010 RC. Has anybody got that running?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Display] attribute is a .NET 4-specific attribute.  Since MVC 2 is compiled against .NET 3.5, the runtime does not recognize this attribute.

See http://aspnet.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=5515 for more information plus workarounds.

**Edit:**

Eh, the work item's not that big.  May as well include it inline. :)

> The [Display] attribute is new in
>   DataAnnotations v4, so MVC 2 can't use
>   it because we're compiled against
>   DataAnnotations v3.5. Use
>   [DisplayName] instead until MVC 3,
>   where we will be compiled against
>   DataAnnotations v4.
>
> You have a few workarounds. When .NET
>   4 RTMs, we will provide a .NET
>   4-specific Futures binary, and that
>   Futures binary will have a metadata
>   provider that understands [Display]
>   and other DataAnnotations v4-specific
>   attributes. Alternatively, if you need
>   a solution right away, subclass the
>   [DisplayName] attribute, make a
>   private DisplayNameAttribute field
>   that's instantiated appropriately, and
>   override the virtual
>   DisplayNameAttribute.DisplayName
>   property so that it delegates to
>   _theWrappedDisplayNameAttribute.GetName().

```
public class MultiCulturalDisplayName : DisplayNameAttribute {
  private DisplayAttribute display;

  public MultiCulturalDisplayName(Type resourceType, string resourceName) {
    this.display = new DisplayAttribute { ResourceType = resourceType, Name = resourceName };
  }

  public override string DisplayName {
    get { return display.GetName(); }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I used a very similar solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you download [ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) assembly, then you can use the DisplayAttribute.  You just need to add `DataAnnotations4ModelMetadataProvider.RegisterProvider();` to your Global.asax.cs

Answer (score 1):

Levi pretty much answered your question, and for the record here is a working version for 3.5

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DisplayNameLocalizedAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public DisplayNameLocalizedAttribute(Type resourceType, string resourceKey)
        : base(LookupResource(resourceType, resourceKey)) {  }

    internal static string LookupResource(Type resourceType, string resourceKey)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = resourceType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(System.Resources.ResourceManager));
        if (property != null)
        {
            return ((ResourceManager)property.GetValue(null, null)).GetString(resourceKey);
        }
        return resourceKey;
    }
}
```