# ASP.Net MVC Multilanguage EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization, multilingual, editorfor

Can I change labels according to users's language with EditorFor and EditorForModel?
Can I use a resource file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right here [DisplayName attribute from Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources)