# Localization DisplayName Attribute

Tags: c#, winforms, attributes

I want to translate property. I have two resources files: `DataResource.resx` and `DataResource.en.resx`. There are `NameString` string(both).
My property:

```
[DisplayName("NameString")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources) solution for localization DataDisplay attribute.

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute: DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceId) 
        : base(GetMessageFromResource(resourceId))
    { }

    private static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceId)
    {
        // TODO: Return the string from the resource file
    }
}
```

But I don't understand what I must to write in `GetMessageFromResource` method.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your custom DataAnnotations attribute your need to write following code in your GetMessageFromResource method:

```
private static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceId)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(DataResource).GetProperty(resourceId, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
}
```

This code should do the job assuming you have an error in your question and there are should be LocalizeDisplayNameAttribute, not the DisplayName one:

```
[DisplayName("NameString")]
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

Anyway I recommend using of lambda accessors for getting localized strings from resources so you can rename/navigate them using your refactoring tool.

Comment: I think I hurried a little with advice to use lambdas since anyway DisplayName attribute itself can't take lambda as constructor's parameter. Forget about it.

Comment: I am using this approach, instead of resource file, i am getting data from database. When I hard coded , it works, but I need user to select the language. So I had a dropdown and I need to change the language when the user changes the dropdown. ie, from Display name attribute I need to pass the locale,how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Also How can I implement localization in buttons. tooltip etc ?

Comment: You can just use static properties of statis resource class which contains string literals you want to localize in your application