# Localization - how to get the client locale in asp.net mvc?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

My question is my title.

```
 Localization - how to get the client locale in asp.net mvc ?
```

I saw some posts regarding based on url routing, is there any way I can get the data from browser or from request to server and process.
Is there any way to get the browser locale from asp.net. I am cretaing custom display attribute to handle localization as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources).

This is because I am using DB for keeping my localized values. My plan is to get the data and using `Display Attribute` , it will display the local values. I need the locale from browser. So is it possible to get the browser's locale and query before rendering based on it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use: `HttpRequest.UserLanguages Property` : Gets a sorted string array of client language preferences.

Refer:

[How to detect browser language](http://forums.asp.net/t/1052219.aspx/1)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.