# Get Browser's date in views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to fetch browser date automatically on a page,

The controller code is as follows:-

```
HttpCookie myCookies = Request.Cookies["MemberID"];
int memberid = int.Parse(myCookies.Value);
var notes = data.Notes.ByCreatedBy(memberid);
return View(notes);
```

Now in the View, I am displaying values as
The notes of current date only should get displayed:-

```
if (@DateTime.Now.Day == item.CreatedOn.Value.Day && @DateTime.Now.Month == item.CreatedOn.Value.Month && @DateTime.Now.Year == item.CreatedOn.Value.Year)
{
<li class="track_notes_li" id='@item.NoteID'><a href="/Notes/Index/@item.NoteID"><span class="first_word">@item.Description,</span> <span>@item.CreatedOn.Value.ToShortDateString()</span></a></li>
}
```

The problem is , the date it is taking in DateTime.Now is the date of the server. So I will get issues when timezone is different. I want to know how to get the browser date so that the current day notes irrespective of timezones should get displayed.

Comment: take a look at this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896613/localization-how-to-get-the-client-locale-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

If you can set a cookie via javascript before this step, it is easy

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` will give you the value you want.

If you can't do that, you will need to detect the user's IP address, map that, and look up the tiemzone of that area.

Comment: How can I set the cookie before this step?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the browser can set cookies. If your website has people visiting the site before this part of your backend code is run, you can do it via javascript

Comment: OK, LEt me try doing it then I will let you know