# Get DisplayName for Model from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

I'm using localization for my ASP.NET Page with a database.

Everything is working fine, a language Dictionary is in the ViewBag, and it's just working for everything, except the DisplayName in the ViewModels.

This is how I'm using translation in the Views:

```
namespace Helpers
{

public static class LocalizationHelper
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Returns the translation for the term
    /// </summary> 
    public static string Translate(this HtmlHelper helper, Term term)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.LangDict;
        Dictionary<string, string> fallbackDic = helper.ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.StandardLangDict;

        string trans = "";
        if (dic.TryGetValue(term.ToString(), out trans))
            return trans;
        else if (fallbackDic.TryGetValue(term.ToString(), out trans))
        {
            return trans;
            //exception trans not available for this lang
            //return fallback language
        }
        else
            return "Translation not set";
    }   
}
```

But I cant use this for the ViewModel because I'cant pass the HTMLHelper Attribute.
And if i decide to write another method like:

```
public static string Translate(Term term)
```

The Viewbag cant work any more. Term is an Enumeration.

Now I have no idea how to get the Data from the Viewbag into the ViewModel.

Comment: You seem to be trying to break the MVC pattern -- HtmlHelper is view-specific, and the view-model shouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: But I have to change the DisplayName in the Models, because of translation. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources this solution is great

Comment: argh, still the problem that I can't use ViewBag outside of Controllers.