# Delegate the property display name translation to a handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

Current code in model:

```
[Display(Name = "E-mail")]
public string EMail { get; set; }
```

Desired code:

```
public string EMail { get; set; }
```

I would like to delegate the translation to a handler, something like this:

> if(propertyName == "EMail")   return "E-mail"

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, I'm assuming that you are trying to implement localisation in your application.

If so, there are two options;

**Resources**

In .NET you can [add Resource (.resx) files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) into your application to handle translation (one resx for each language). Then you can specify the Resource by specifying the `ResourceType` property of your `Display` attribute. For example;

```
public class Model
{
  [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Strings))]
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Custom attribute**

Alternatively, if you are set on implementing this in a handler then you could implement a custom attribute, [as demonstrated in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431333/displayname-attribute-from-resources).

Edit: Modified from the example in the above post.

If you add a new Resource file to your project - say Strings.resx and add "HelloWorld" as a field. You can then create a new attribute, such as `LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute`;

```
public class LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
  public LocalisedDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceId)
    : base(GetMessageFromResource(resourceId))
  {
  }

  private static string GetMessageFromResource(string resourceId)
  {
    // "Strings" is the name of your resource file.
    ResourceManager resourceManager = Strings.ResourceManager;
    return resourceManager.GetString(resourceId);
  }
}
```

You can then use it as follows;

```
public class Model
{
  [LocalisedDisplayName("HelloWorld")]
  public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if I can help further,

Matt

Comment: I would prefer not to write this line:
[Display (Name = "Email" Resource Type = typeof (Resources.Strings))]
just this:
public string Email { get; set; }

Comment: OK, what are your thoughts on the other option - the custom attribute?

Comment: I do not like that I have to remember to specify the attribute in all fields. Surprising that it can not be done smarter.

Comment: But it may be I will have to take the alternative. How is it done?