# LabelFor() in a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a strongly-typed model associated with it

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
                  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SomeNamespace.SomeViewModel>" %>
```

The SomeViewModel looks like this

```
class SomeViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> Foos {get; set;}
}
```

and say Foo is

```
class Foo
{
   public string Bar {get; set;}
}
```

and in the view

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Foos) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.LabelFor(f => f.Bar) %>
        </td>
```

I'm not sure how to display `Bar` property in `item` using `Html.LabelFor()`

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you getting an error with that code?

Comment: @AndyC I don't know how to get at Bar for the loop variable `item`. f => f.[No Bar here. only Foos]`

Comment: @TheOtherGuy, most examples i've seen have hard coded the labels as table headers and then done the for each after. Are you displaying yours in a table? is there a reason you need the label in your foreach (it will just constantly repeat your label for every row)

Comment: @Manatherin I have a collection of Foo objects and i'm trying to display the Bar property for each Foo in each table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
<% for (var i=0; i<Model.Foos.Count();i++) { %> 
    <tr> 
        <td> 
            <%= Html.LabelFor(f => f.Foos[i].Bar) %> 
        </td>
```

The LabelFor extension uses a lamda expression to go from your Model object to the selected property, consider f a substituion variable for your model. So you need a way to get from your model to your chosen property.   You are telling LabelFor, create a local variable called f and assign it with the value of your model.  then use the bit after the => to determine the target property.

If you are desperate to use the foreach, you would have to have a way of translating item back to a property of the original model, (e.g. for an array as Gledrius said `x=>x.Foos[Model.Foos.IndexOf(foo)])`

failing that if you just want the text value

use '<%= item %>' instead of the whole labelfor or if you have ASP.NET 4 and MVC2 or better use `<%: item %>` for that HTML encoding goodness

Comment: I will try this but is it not possible to use `foreach` ?

Comment: LabelFor takes an expression as a parameter so you can't pass it an object (so you can't pass it your item variable).

Comment: You asked for a foreach example and I provided one that works but then you accepted the answer that doesn't use foreach. o_O

Comment: A downside of this approach is that you end up with multiple `<label>

Answer (score 48):

Do this instead:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Foos) { %>      
<tr>          
    <td>              
        <%= Html.LabelFor(f => item.Bar) %>          
    </td>
<% } %>
```

Instead of f => f.Bar do f => item.Bar, where item is the name of the variable in your foreach loop.

Here is the much more beautiful razor syntax :)

```
@foreach( var item in Model.Foos ) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.LabelFor(f => item.Bar)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(f => item.Bar)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: That is awesome.  Not sure the how and why though.  An explanation of the need for the mismatch would be helpful for the noobs.

Comment: Related question: How do I do this and have `TextBoxFor` produce a different ID for each item so I can update properly?

Comment: Im not sure why this isnt the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just write a custom extension that's not tied directly to the Model of the page.

```
   public static MvcHtmlString LabelForItem<T, V>(this HtmlHelper html, T obj, Expression<Func<T, V>> expression) 
   {
       Func<T,V> func = expression.Compile();
       V val = func(obj);
       return html.Label(val.ToString());
   }
```

And you'd use it, like this:

```
@foreach (Foo foo in Model)
{
    <p>
       @(Html.LabelForItem<Foo, string>(foo, f => f.Name))
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312880/html-labelfor-specified-text-asp-net-mvc-2), looks like you need to specify the [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) on the property:

```
[DisplayName("My Bar")]
public string Bar { get; set; }
```

Comment: That's not what he's asking for.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know how to go about specifying the property Bar. Is it `f => f.Bar`(doesn't compile) or `item => item.Bar` (doesn't compile either)

Comment: @TheOtherGuy - How about `Html.LabelFor(x => item.Bar)`

Answer (score 0):

if Foos would be list, it would look like this:

```
Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Foos[Model.Foos.IndexOf(item)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over your Foo's but not using the item variable at all.

Comment: How do i use `item` ? when i do `item => item.Bar`, I get `A parameter named item cannot be declared in this scope ... `